# Nested queries in SQL finding min and max using group by

Tags: mysql, sql

Problem I'm trying to solve:

Find the address *district(s)* *name(s)* such that the minimal postal code in the district(s) is maximal over all the districts. Make sure your query ignores empty postal codes and district names.

I can find the minimum postal code easily enough. I am having trouble writing the nested query to then find the maximum postal code from these results.

So far I've used:

```
SELECT min(postal_code), district 
FROM address 
WHERE district != '' AND postal_code != '' 
GROUP BY district;
```

Comment: See http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Answer (score 0):

You cab Either use this

```
Select Rank() Over (Partition by district Order by postal_code DESC ) AS 

Rank,district, postal_code  from address district != '' AND postal_code != ''
```

Or You can this

```
 Select Rank() Over (Partition by district Order by postal_code DESC ) AS 

Rank,district, postal_code into #Temp  from address district != '' AND postal_code != ''
```

Now use

```
Select district, postal_code from #Temp
```

Comment: I think this is SQL Server code but the question is tagged `mySQL`.